# How to create routine in PHP to go to direct link?

Tags: php

Friends, I need help to create a routine (`function`) in `php` to solve the hypothetical link below. But I'm not sure where to start:

The initial link captured by preg_match_all is in the format:

```
http://www.exemplo.br/test.html
```

What you send to:

```
http://www.page1.br/sub/exemplo1.php?txt=texto12
```

In the previous link you need to click on the advertisement 3 times to have access to the ads4 (below). Only in the source code of ads4 is the direct link.

```
ads1 - http://ad.net/sub/exemplo1.php?txt=texto12
ads2 - http://test.in/sub/exemplo1.php?txt=texto12
ads3 - http://outro.bz/sub/exemplo1.php?txt=texto12
ads4 - http://exemplo.com/sub/exemplo1end.php?txt=texto12
```

Direct link available in ads4 source code:

```
http://www.end.com/sub/exemplo1/texto12.txt
```

I could convert the first link at the end, but I'm lost in how to do a routine that exits from where I am (`preg_match_all` link) to the text12.txt

```
http://www.page1.br/sub/exemplo1.php?txt=(.*?)
http://exemplo.com/sub/exemplo1end.php?txt=($1)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need a function that puts you through all ads and retrieves the final file, right? In that case, I'd suggest you simply retrieve relevant text from the first URL and visit the last one from there. If it's unpredictable, you'll probably need to parse the HTML in each file, find the relevant link (by ID, perhaps?) and follow it. That won't be very simple.

Comment: @gchiconi, What changes in the structure of the initial link to the end (where, in the source, is the link of the file), is basically the word "end".
The problem is that I'm a beginner in php learning and I'm not sure how to create the function.